# cant save associated new records in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

To save new records in associated data with a many to 1 and a many to many as below what do I do ? I cant get it to save my data .
I get an error on trying to save a to the guardian without an id but it is a new record and I couldn't this working

controller

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $mydata=$this->request->data; 

          $guardian =$this->Guardians->newEntity();
          $guardian->guardian_first_name = $mydata['Guardians']['guardian_first_name'];
          $guardian->guardian_last_name = $mydata['Guardians']['guardian_last_name'];
          $guardian->guardian_mobile = $mydata['Guardians']['guardian_mobile'];
          $guardian->guardian_email = $mydata['Guardians']['guardian_email'];


         $student = $this->Students->newEntity( $mydata,['associated' => ['AvailabilityForStudents','Subjects','Guardians']] );
         $student->guardians = [ $guardian];

         $val=   $this->Students->save($student,[
                'validate' => false ]); 


       public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('students');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');


        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Guardians', [
            'foreignKey' => 'guardian_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('AvailabilityForStudents', [
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
        ]);


        $this->belongsToMany('Subjects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
            'joinTable' => 'students_subjects'
        ]);
    }                 
 http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations

update-returned data
[
    'first_name' => 'a1',
    'last_name' => 'a2',
    'student_mobile' => '',
    'school' => '9',
    'class_year' => '9',
    'tutor_gender_preference' => 'No Preference',
    'doing_assessment' => '0',
    'tutoring_typest_id' => '1',
    'address_street' => '1 gghh',
    'address_suburb' => 'seagg',
    'address_postcode' => '3111',
    'address_state' => 'Vic',
    'address_lat' => '',
    'address_long' => '',
    'school_address_street' => '',
    'school_address_suburb' => '',
    'school_address_postcode' => '',
    'school_address_lat' => '',
    'school_address_long' => '',
    'Guardians' => [
        'guardian_first_name' => 'aa',
        'guardian_last_name' => 'aa',
        'guardian_phone' => '03534535',
        'guardian_mobile' => '0000000000',
        'guardian_email' => 'a@ww.com'
    ],
    'subjects' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '1'
        ]
    ],
    'AvailabilityForStudents' => [
        'Monday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Monday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Tuesday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Tuesday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Wednesday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Wednesday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Thursday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Thursday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Friday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Friday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Saturday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Saturday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Sunday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Sunday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ]
    ]
]

patched data
object(App\Model\Entity\Student) {

    'first_name' => 'a1',
    'last_name' => 'a2',
    'student_mobile' => '',
    'school' => '9',
    'class_year' => (int) 9,
    'tutor_gender_preference' => 'No Preference',
    'doing_assessment' => (int) 0,
    'tutoring_typest_id' => (int) 1,
    'address_street' => '1 gghh',
    'address_suburb' => 'seagg',
    'address_postcode' => '3111',
    'address_state' => 'Vic',
    'address_lat' => '',
    'address_long' => '',
    'school_address_street' => '',
    'school_address_suburb' => '',
    'school_address_postcode' => '',
    'school_address_lat' => '',
    'school_address_long' => '',
    'Guardians' => [
        'guardian_first_name' => 'aa',
        'guardian_last_name' => 'aa',
        'guardian_phone' => '03534535',
        'guardian_mobile' => '0000000000',
        'guardian_email' => 'a@ww.com'
    ],
    'subjects' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Subject) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'English: Prep- Grade 3',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Subjects'

        }
    ],
    'AvailabilityForStudents' => [
        'Monday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Monday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Tuesday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Tuesday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Wednesday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Wednesday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Thursday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Thursday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Friday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Friday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Saturday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Saturday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ],
        'Sunday' => [
            'weekday' => 'Sunday',
            'not_available' => '0',
            'start_time' => '9:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00'
        ]
    ],
    'student_enq' => false,
    'user_id' => (int) 7,
    'student_inactive' => false,
    'acknowledge' => (int) 0,
    'is_email_notify' => (int) 0,
    'days_joined' => (int) 0,
    'satisfaction_rating' => (int) 0,
    'student_unallocated' => false,
    'admin_satisfaction_rating' => (int) 0,
    'another_assessment' => (int) 0,
    'numeracy_active' => (int) 0,
    'is_waiting_assessment' => (int) 0,
    'group_status' => (int) 0,
    'address_billing' => '4',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'student_mobile' => true,
        'school' => true,
        'class_year' => true,
        'tutor_gender_preference' => true,
        'doing_assessment' => true,
        'tutoring_typest_id' => true,
        'address_street' => true,
        'address_suburb' => true,
        'address_postcode' => true,
        'address_state' => true,
        'address_lat' => true,
        'address_long' => true,
        'school_address_street' => true,
        'school_address_suburb' => true,
        'school_address_postcode' => true,
        'school_address_lat' => true,
        'school_address_long' => true,
        'Guardians' => true,
        'subjects' => true,
        'AvailabilityForStudents' => true,
        'student_enq' => true,
        'user_id' => true,
        'student_inactive' => true,
        'acknowledge' => true,
        'is_email_notify' => true,
        'days_joined' => true,
        'satisfaction_rating' => true,
        'student_unallocated' => true,
        'admin_satisfaction_rating' => true,
        'another_assessment' => true,
        'numeracy_active' => true,
        'is_waiting_assessment' => true,
        'group_status' => true,
        'address_billing' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Students'

}
```

Comment: Why do not bake controller? So you get all the functionality out-of-box.

Comment: I have  a bake controller and the function out of the box doesn't suffice

Comment: if students belongsTo guardians shouldn't it be `$student->guardian =  $guardian`?

Comment: I have no idea but I am just guessing now as I cant see an example. I have tried a lot of combinations and this solution didnt work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the similar problem and after all R&D, I tried this code and it worked. Hope you'll also get benefited. Here the code goes:

Let's say you have a controller "UsersController" associated with "RolesController" with "id". Then add the below line of code in your action under UsersController:

```
$this->loadModel('Roles');
$roles = $this->Roles->find('list');
$roles = $roles->toArray();
$this->set(compact('roles'));
```

Now make the following changes in your action's view file in Template folder:

```
echo $this->Form->select('role_id', $roles);
```

Here, we have assigned that variable to our form field.

With these changes, you should be able to do your task. If still face any issue, feel free to ask in comments.

KEEP CODING! HAVE FUN! :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest splitting the entity creation.

First, create a new entity with `$student = $this->Students->newEntity();`

And then patch you data to the entity like :

`$student = $this->Student->patchEntity($mydata,['associated' => ['AvailabilityForStudents','Subjects','Guardians']]);`

Maybe the patchEntity() method understand the association in a better manner.
Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: I have done this before with the code you are suggesting and it doesnt work.I dont get an error but it doesnt save.  I have no idea how to save an associated record

Comment: I tried this again from the answer given and it doesnt work. The problem is it is not creating a new associated record for Guardian as it gives a Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'guardian_id' doesn't have a default value . I will have to mark down the answer until it is revised

Comment: It is used to mark your associations as being `dirty` so they can be overlooked when the saving is executed in the DB.

Comment: Here you have more detailed info : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified

Comment: Didnt work sorry and dirty doesnt seem to be for new records.  I cant believe i still cant get this to save/

Comment: What does your `$this->request->data` look like? What does your entity look like after you call `patchEntity`? This is working fine for many people, so it's likely a problem in how your incoming data is formatted.

Comment: i have entered the returned data in the original post above. The fields that are null can be null. The error get is that it expects a guardian id filed to be set but a new record shouldnt have such a field. then after this is the patched data